# How use vue-sidebar-menu in vue-cli3 generated app?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I need sidebar in my vue-cli3 generated app
Here is part of my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.15",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.7.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.26",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-sidebar-menu": "^3.11.1"
  },
```

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/fontawesome'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import VueSidebarMenu from 'vue-sidebar-menu'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import 'vue-sidebar-menu/dist/vue-sidebar-menu.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(VueSidebarMenu)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

app.js

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <sidebar-menu :menu="menu" />
    <div class="container float-right">
      <router-view/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and in result:

- sidebar not show fontawesome icons
- sidebar in expanded state hide *content* div

[image]

How I can resolve this issue? May be I need using another sidebar component?

Answer (score 6):

Hi~ Please flow steps as below :

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

then in main.js, import css and js file

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';
Vue.use(VueSidebarMenu);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me some time :)